# how to select data from primary key in a table when it's not equal to forign key in another table?

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

Here's what I have:
1. I have a table called "International_Codes" with 2 columns (int_code_id, desc)
2. I have another table called "size_charts" which has (int_code_id, xs, s, m, l, xl)

I have a "select list", which contains all "international codes" except the ones already in "size_charts" table.

here's what I did:

```
SELECT international_codes.int_code_id, international_codes.desc
FROM   international_codes, size_charts
WHERE  international_codes.int_code_id <> size_charts.int_code_id
```

It gives me duplicate entries and wrong data.
I also tried to use join left, but get wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT international_codes.int_code_id, international_codes.desc
FROM   international_codes LEFT JOIN size_charts
       ON international_codes.int_code_id = size_charts.int_code_id
WHERE  size_charts.int_code_id IS NULL
```

that will return all rows from `international_codes` and only the rows from `size_charts` that matches. If there is no match, `size_charts.int_code_id` will be NULL.

Selecting all rows where `size_charts.int_code_id IS NULL` will return all rows from international_codes that have no match on size_charts table.